# Geoserver SLD using PropertyIsEqualTo And PropertyIsLike

Tags: geoserver, sql-server, sld

I have two SLD rules one using  PropertyIsEqualTo and another using PropertyIsLike

**Using  PropertyIsEqualTo**

```xml
<Rule>
          <Name>Vendor FirstVendor</Name>
          <Title>FristVendor</Title>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            <ogc:PropertyName>Vendor</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>firstVendor</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <PointSymbolizer>
            <Graphic>
              <Mark>
                <WellKnownName>circle</WellKnownName>
                <Fill>
                  <CssParameter name="fill">#0033CC</CssParameter>
                </Fill>
              </Mark>
              <Size>8</Size>
            </Graphic>
          </PointSymbolizer>              
     </Rule>
```

**Using PropertyIsLike**

```xml
<ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:PropertyIsLike  wildCard="*" singleChar="." escape="!">
            <ogc:PropertyName>Vendor</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>firstVendor*</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsLike>
</ogc:Filter>
```

The SLD using Like works fine where as using equal does not work at all.I have seen the string in database well there is not leading or trailing spaces.

*Geoserver is taking space at the end of literal. That was the issue. I added space to PropertyName eg **Vendor_***

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to your problem. I seem to be having the exact same issue using PropertyIsEqualTo. I have looked at the resulting query that Geoserver creates and run this on the database. The database returns the results as expected but geoserver does not seem to render anything for the layer. Any help is much appreciated. Apologies for not posting this as a comment but it won't allow me to as I just created an account.

Comment: @k9ty yes I found the solution the problem is there is some kind of bug or I don't know what's it the sld won't work you should use <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:PropertyIsLike  wildCard="*" singleChar="." escape="!">           
            <ogc:PropertyName>Vendor</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>V1*</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsLike>
          </ogc:Filter>

Comment: @k9ty here we have used the query "like" it the solution for now I guess. I could not solbe the problem with captDragon solution as there was validation error.

Answer (score 4):

Try adding `matchCase="true"` like this:

```xml
<ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo matchCase="true">
    <ogc:PropertyName>Vendor</ogc:PropertyName>
    <ogc:Literal>firstVendor</ogc:Literal>
</ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
```

I know it doesn't really make sense, but comparing yours to mine, that's the only difference i see.

Comment: Attribute 'matchCase' is not allowed to appear in element 'ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo'

Comment: What is not allowing you? It's part of the [OGC spec](http://schemas.opengis.net/filter/2.0/filter.xsd).

Comment: it works partially but geoserver validate button generates error

Comment: What's the error? And do you have this `xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"` at the top of the xml file?

Comment: Yes. *xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" 
    xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" 
    xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"*

Comment: What's the error say?

Comment: "Attribute 'matchCase' is not allowed to appear in element 'ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo'" This is the error :)

Comment: Do you get an error without the `matchCase="true"`? If so, what is it? If not, it simply does not return any results?

Comment: No errror without matchCase="true". without matchCase="true" no result is returned but with matchCase(if I submit with error) returns results but only few 3/4 out of 1200.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is quite late but I was just struggling with this same issue.

I used "excapeChar" instead of "escape" and GeoServer accepted it:

```
<ogc:PropertyIsLike wildCard="%" singleChar="#" escapeChar="!">
<ogc:PropertyName>Name</ogc:PropertyName>
<ogc:Literal>%Value%</ogc:Literal>
```